# How to get the device of a corrupted USB Stick on linux?

Tags: linux, usb

In order to try to rescue a USB stick which has probably a corrupted allocation table, I would like to get the device.

I'm using Ubuntu 10 as a guest in VirtualBox, Host: Win7. Windows just tells me that the USB is not formatted.

When `tail -f /var/log/messages` and I insert the USB stick, there won't be anything appended.
`fdisk -l` does not show anything.

`dmesg` writes out this (slightly shortened). I'm not sure if it says anything about my USB stick.

```
[    3.863790] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[    4.128805] udev: starting version 151
[    5.486258] Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - version 7.3.21-k5-NAPI
[    5.486354] Copyright (c) 1999-2006 Intel Corporation.
[    5.486922] ahci 0000:00:0d.0: version 3.0
[    5.506298] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] enabled at IRQ 5
[    5.506348] PCI: setting IRQ 5 as level-triggered
[    5.506396] ahci 0000:00:0d.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKA] -> GSI 5 (level, low) -> IRQ 5
[    5.506714] ahci: SSS flag set, parallel bus scan disabled
[    5.507173] ahci 0000:00:0d.0: AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 1 ports 3 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    5.507218] ahci 0000:00:0d.0: flags: 64bit ncq stag only ccc 
[    5.507299] ahci 0000:00:0d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    5.559375] scsi2 : ahci
[    5.559617] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf0842000 port 0xf0842100 irq 5
[    5.587498] e1000 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 10 (level, low) -> IRQ 10
[    5.588364] e1000 0000:00:03.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    6.301190] e1000: 0000:00:03.0: e1000_probe: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 08:00:27:8a:f3:ec
[    6.364441] e1000: eth0: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    6.369355] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 9
[    6.369437] PCI: setting IRQ 9 as level-triggered
[    6.369474] e1000 0000:00:08.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 9 (level, low) -> IRQ 9
[    6.369575] e1000 0000:00:08.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    7.127984] e1000: 0000:00:08.0: e1000_probe: (PCI:33MHz:32-bit) 08:00:27:ae:ac:59
[    7.129255] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    7.163686] ata3.00: ATA-6: VBOX HARDDISK, 1.0, max UDMA/133
[    7.163724] ata3.00: 16777216 sectors, multi 128: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[    7.165107] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    7.171587] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      VBOX HARDDISK    1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    7.174740] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    7.197357] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 16777216 512-byte logical blocks: (8.58 GB/8.00 GiB)
[    7.204593] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    7.204621] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    7.205256] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    7.218249] e1000: eth1: e1000_probe: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    7.221165]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    7.393432] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    7.456709] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
[    7.490268] input: VirtualBox USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input4
[    7.491470] generic-usb 0003:80EE:0021.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [VirtualBox USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:06.0-1/input0
[    7.491643] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    7.492742] usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
[    8.703587] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
[   26.040624] Adding 407544k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:407544k 
[   26.231877] udev: starting version 151
```

Comment: That dmesg doesn't say anything about a USB insertion. Is it running in a VM? Looks like it, and doesn't look like it has access to the USB device.

Comment: Did you attach the USB stick to the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if a USB drive not recognised by the host can be detected by the guest. I would play safe and use a Linux livecd to make an USB drive image and try to recover the data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. VirtualBox is the problem here. On another not-virtual-box installation dmesg showed it as sdb. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your 8GB USB mentioned here

```
[    7.174740] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    7.197357] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 16777216 512-byte logical blocks: (8.58 GB/8.00 GiB)
[    7.204593] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    7.204621] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    7.205256] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

There is a very good chance its your system drive though.

Whats the output of this command

```
ls -la /dev
```

ive had mixed results with USB's and VM's, i would use a bootdisk on real hardware to be sure.

Comment: This is the VirtualBox partition. the ls shows only the sda, no other. Actually, I tried it on a wubi installation in the office today and there the USB is showing. Thank you anyways.